# Stuck on the boot menu with multiple [OK]- Unable to login to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, login

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot)
Processor: Intel Pentium

I cannot login to Ubuntu.

While trying to login in from boot menu to Ubuntu it is showing ^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D.....[immediately after selecting Ubuntu from the boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfhcH.jpg)...

Then it is going through a screen with multiple green [OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frgIw.jpg)

Then stopping and starting UID 121][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX3BX.jpg).

After that it gets stuck at the Ubuntu purple login screen.

I can login to Ubuntu through "Advanced Ubuntu options". There I checked that while typing, the left arrow key is not working (Is it connected to ^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D.....!!!!).

I tried some code from Google and YouTube but all in vain.

It was all going well before. I don't know how it happened. I had plugged in my USB cable while the laptop was booting that time, when it all started. Can it be the reason‌?

Comment: It seems like a key is stuck. You should try removing the cap and cleaning it for starters.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the laptop keyboard interally, and instead use an external keyboard? I disabled the internal keyboard using "xinput float", but at the boot menu, the internal keyboard is still working. So the problem still persists.